# How to undo split panels in iTerm2?

Tags: macos, iterm2

I've started using iTerm2. I like the functionality of splitting panels using

```
Cmd + d
```

and

```
Cmd + Shift + d
```

But how can I ***undo*** this splitting?

---

In the standard terminal `Cmd + d` can be undone using `Cmd + Shift + d`, but in iTerm it's used for horizontal split.

Comment: Ask on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Right click -> move to new window -> create new tab in new window -> drag tab of original session back into first window -> close new window

Comment: Shift-Cmd-D works too actually. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87202/how-to-switch-or-close-the-new-split-terminal-pane

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I like the functionality of splitting panels using `Cmd + d`

Note that whilst this even in [iTerm2's official docs](https://iterm2.com/documentation-one-page.html) is described as *Split Panes*

> **Split Panes**
>
> iTerm2 allows you to divide a tab into many rectangular "panes", each of which is a different terminal session. The shortcuts `cmd-d` and `cmd-shift-d` divide an existing session vertically or horizontally, respectively. You can navigate among split panes with `cmd-opt-arrow` or `cmd-[` and `cmd-]`. **You can "maximize" the current pane--hiding all others in that tab--with `cmd-shift-enter`. Pressing the shortcut again restores the hidden panes.**

if you only start with a single terminal session, the splitting comes with the side effect of *starting another session*. As per the docs, you can either maximize a single pane using

```
Cmd + Shift + Enter
```

which leaves the hidden panes alive as active terminal sessions. Moreover, you can kill the terminal session of the active pane using

```
Cmd + w
```

Which comes with the iTerm2 side effect that the corresponding pane will also be closed.

Note that repeated use of `Cmd + w` will, after closing all terminal sessions, eventually close the final terminal session and the iTerm2 tab itself.

Example of `Cmd + w` *to close terminal session* (with the effect of closing the panes that used to hold them):

[image]

Comment: I like the blue arrow showing your current directory. What plugin is that?

Comment: @Dagrooms [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh), using a tweaked agnostic theme, I believe. Note that you will need to install some powerline fonts to use the fancier themes such as agnostic (especially for its annotation features when the `pwd` is in a git repo.

Comment: This does not undo the split, it just exits the terminal that the cursor is in.

Comment: @HenryGrantham Answer updated to clarify this (as well as expanded with pane maximization).

Comment: confirmed this does not undo the split by returning session to its own tab.